# How can I add a character into a specified position into string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar field that stores dates like `20210331`

I need to change these values to `2021-03-31`

Comment: :facepalm: `select CAST('20210331' AS DATE);` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f30bb40866ee26b4e37a6afcc826b56d

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ugly, but using `CONCAT` and `SUBSTR` will achieve this (replace `myCol` with the name of your column):

```
SELECT  CONCAT(
            SUBSTR(myCol, 1 , 4),
            '-',
            SUBSTR(myCol, 5 , 2),
            '-',
            SUBSTR(myCol, 7 , 2)
        )
```

Output:

```
2021-03-31
```

Using `SUBSTR` takes a *substring* from the column, in this case characters:

- 1-4 (year)
- 5-6 (month)
- 7-8 (day)

`CONCAT` then *concatenates* (or combines) these into a single string by joining each part with a hypen in-between.